Position labels dynamically based on their point feature values
In QGIS I go to the layer properties and in the labels/positioning section in the 'Offset X, Y' field I click on 'Defined data overwrite' and enter the following expression:
 'array("label_offset_X", "label_offset_Y")'

The labels are set correctly for each point according to the respective values ​​present in the attribute table. How can I replicate this with Python code!?
I'll post the def of the plugin I'm developing; the "point_layer" layer is a point layer.
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QColor
from qgis._core import QgsPalLayerSettings, QgsTextFormat, QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling, QgsExpression

def draw_labels(point_layer):
    # aggiunge le etichette al layer punti
    label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    label_settings.fieldName = "id"
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)
    text_format.setColor(QColor("red"))
    label_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    label_settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint     # imposta gli offset individuali per ogni etichetta

    # Crea un'espressione per creare un array con gli offset
    #offset_expression = QgsExpression('array("label_offset_X", "label_offset_Y")')
    offset_expression = QgsExpression("make_point(label_offset_X, label_offset_X)")

    # Imposta gli offset come definiti dall'utente
    label_settings.dataDefinedOffset = True
    label_settings.dataDefinedOffsetExpression = offset_expression


    # 'array("label_offset_X", "label_offset_Y")'


    labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings)
    point_layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    point_layer.setLabeling(labeling)
    point_layer.triggerRepaint()


The code snippet below will show you how to replicate the data defined OffsetXY settings via PyQGIS:
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QFont, QColor
from qgis.core import (QgsPalLayerSettings, QgsTextFormat,
                        QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling, QgsExpression,
                        QgsPropertyCollection, QgsProperty, Qgis)

def draw_labels(point_layer):
    label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    label_settings.fieldName = "id"
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial"))
    text_format.setSize(12)
    text_format.setColor(QColor("red"))
    label_settings.setFormat(text_format)
    label_settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
    #From 3.26 onwards use:
    #label_settings.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.OverPoint
    props = QgsPropertyCollection()
    props.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Property.OffsetXY, QgsProperty.fromExpression('array("label_offset_X", "label_offset_Y")'))
    label_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(props)
    labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings)
    point_layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    point_layer.setLabeling(labeling)
    point_layer.triggerRepaint()
    
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
draw_labels(lyr)


Perfect, the code works fine. Thank you.

@Wolverine, that's great. In that case would mind accepting the answer please?

Of course, sorry, I'm not very familiar with how stackoverflow works.  I checked the green box, is that right?
